# meaning of "Size of one child value" limit 10Mb for firebase

Tags: firebase

The firebase documentation specifies the limit for "Size of one child value" is 10Mb.
Does that mean the size of the JSON object of that child?

For example, using example in the documentation:

```
{
"users": {
    "mchen": {
          "friends": { "brinchen": true },
          "name": "Mary Chen",
          // our child node appears in the existing JSON tree
          "widgets": { "one": true, "three": true }
    },
    "brinchen": { ... },
    "hmadi": { ... }
  }
}
```

Is node "users" considered as a child here? if so, does it mean if the # of users gets large(like hundreds of thousands, assuming each user has 100 bytes data), then the sum of sizes of all users will be exceeding the 10Mb limit? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the documentation says the **value** of a single node can be at most 10MB. The child nodes under a location are not considered a value, they're just... child nodes.

A tree can be larger than 10MB. Logically thinking this also makes sense: otherwise the entire database could never be larger than 10MB, which is not true.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.